# Dynamic post_logout_uri and redirect_uri in IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I came across an issue where one of my clients is sending postlogouturi with dynamic parameters.

I have registered a client in ClientStore from the IdentityServer4 side

```
new Client({
  clientId: "some_id",
  redirectUri: {"https://www.example.com/callback1","https://www.example.com/callback2"},
  postLogoutUri: {"https://www.example.com/postlogout1","https://www.example.com/postlogout2"},
  ... some other config,
})
```

Here the client is a React application and they are using the oidc-client library to connect with the Identity server

If they use the below config everything is working fine and we can get postlogouturi on the IdentityServer side and redirect clients to that URL once they logout.

```
var config = {
    authority: "https://www.ouridentityserver.com",
    client_id: "some_id",
    redirect_uri: "https://www.example.com/callback1",
    response_type: "id_token token",
    scope:"openid profile api1",
    post_logout_redirect_uri : "https://www.example.com/postlogout1",
};
var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);
```

But the client's requirement is to add some query parameters to the post-logout-Uri to the above config

```
post_logout_redirect_uri : "https://www.example.com/postlogout1?language=chinese&param1=value1&param2=value2"
```

Here language, value1, and value2 are dynamic so we cannot register the client with those exact post-logout-uris on the IdentityServer side.
So whenever they use those dynamic parameters on postlogouturi IdentityServer was getting postlogouturi as **null** and was not able to redirect to that URI when they logout.

can someone help me to understand is there any way to validate that dynamic uris on the IdentityServer side? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Definitely, there is no other option than registering URL in-client store. PostlogoutUrl is something where IdS4 should redirect back when a user successfully logged out which can be multiple pages/routes but clearly not a dynamic URL. I can understand that it's a client/consumer specific requirement and IdS4 is a global/central token provider (Which is being consumed by all types of clients) and should not support consumer-specific requirements it's the consumer's responsibility to store these values at the client-side and then use them when the user logged out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some R&D, I have some how managed to find a solution for this using HttpContextAccessor.
Whenever any user clicks logout from client side the request comes to IdentityServer and we can get the post_logout_redirect_uri of client dynamically with the below code.

```
 var dynamicPostLogoutUri = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["post_logout_redirect_uri"].ToString();
```

once we get the post_logout_redirect_uri (which has dynamic query parameters) we can simply register that on ClientStore for that client at the runtime dynamically.

```
   new Client({
      clientId: "some_id",
      redirectUris: {"https://www.example.com/callback1","https://www.example.com/callback2"},
      postLogoutUris: {dynamicPostLogoutUri ,"https://www.example.com/postlogout1","https://www.example.com/postlogout2"},
      ... some other config,
    })
```

I'm sharing this solution as I thought this answer may be useful for others.

**EDIT 1:** Before registering dynamic postlogouturi in the clientStore you can write your won logic to validate the uri.

```
if(ourValidation(postlogouturi)){
    postLogoutUris.Add(dynamicPostLogoutUri);
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Even better solution is to use custom redirect uri and postlogout uri validator service from IdentityServer.

In startup.cs register the service

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
       .AddRedirectUriValidator<CustomRedirectUriValidator>()
```

CustomRedirectUriValidator.cs

```
public class CustomRedirectUriValidator : IRedirectUriValidator
    {
        
        public Task<bool> IsPostLogoutRedirectUriValidAsync(string requestedUri, Client client)
        {
            // you can write custom logic to validate the uri and return true or false
        }

        public Task<bool> IsRedirectUriValidAsync(string requestedUri, Client client)
        {
           // you can write custom logic to validate the uri and return true or false
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please write example of CustomRedirectUriValidator ?